# Issue with passing class data from apex to javascript in LWC

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning-web-components, wrapper-class, lwc-wire-adapter

I am trying to return multiple values from the apex to javascript using wire decorator. Because of functions in apex cannot return multiple values at the same time, I  am returning custom class wrapper which has instance variables mapped to values I want to return. 
I tested the apex code using the developer console, it's working fine. Problem is at the javascript side, instead of getting the custom class wrapper instance, I am getting empty object `{}`.


Type of values I am trying to return can be Standard Objects or Custom Objects.


Thank you.

Comment: It'd help if you would include the relevant bits of code that you've written so far (both the Javascript and the Apex). Doing that helps show that you've made a good-faith effort to resolve your problem on your own. It's also somewhere between hard and impossible to debug code issues without seeing the code. You can [edit] your question to add these details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The attributes in the custom class that you have created should have the AuraEnabled annotation set on them. Then those attributes will be accessible on the javascript side.

```
public class MultiValueReturn {
    @AuraEnabled
    public Decimal val1;
    @AuraEnabled
    public String val2;
}
```

Comment: That worked. I thought we can have AuraEnabled annotation for only static values and methods. Thank you.

Comment: Lifesaver! Such a small annotation, such a big difference. Where did you find this?